# Java object Random always returns error: "Random.nextInt(int) line: not available"

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am currently writing a program for school to test the efficiency of different sorting algorithms. When trying to create arrays of random numbers, the Random object always gives an error.

`arrays` is type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` and is a set of the arrays I test

`numTrials` is type `int` and is the number of trials per size of array (I am testing different array sizes at different powers of 10)

This is my code to fill the arrays right now:

```
Random randGen = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Math.pow(10.0, i / numTrials); j++)
    {
        arrays.get(i).set(j, randGen.nextInt(i));
    }
}
```

I tried seeding as well by calling `randGen.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis())` but the error still showed up every time.

Here is a screengrab of the error:
[image: Error screengrab]

Comment: What is the exact `class` of `Random`?

Comment: That error message sounds unlikely to me - is that *exactly* what you're seeing? Is this a compile-time error or an exception? What is the type of `arrays`?

Comment: Except for the fact that `arrays.get(i)` might return null and `.set(j, ...)` does not work if the list is too small, this code seems pretty correct to me. Are you sure you imported `java.util.Random`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Random comes from `java.util.Random` @JonSkeet `arrays` is type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` as I said in the question. I also edited the question with a screengrab of the error. @Clashsoft I made sure I have it imported. Everything is initialized earlier in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextInt()` has following check

```
if (bound <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadBound);
```

As your first param passed to the `nextInt()` is zero, you are getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting something like `random number's bound must be positive` since you can generate random numbers only for positive numbers.

Comment: Good point, but this doesn't quite answer the question. Would be a great comment though.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt but that's not the exception one could expect from Random. I think OP is trying to debug something and he is changing the code and as a result he might be seeing that.